# Overwriting one sheet in an existing excel file with python

Tags: python, save, openpyxl, export-to-excel, overwrite

I have an existing excel file called `test.xlsx`, which has a table in sheet one `tables`, which points to the data in the second sheet `data`.

I want to keep the `tables` sheet and its table while overwriting the entirety of the `data` sheet with the contents of the `new_df` dataframe.

My program:

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
file_to_update = r'C:\folder\test.xlsx'

book = load_workbook(file_to_update)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_to_update, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

new_df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\folder\other_csv.csv', sep = '|')
new_df.to_excel(writer, index = False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

The previously existing data is still there, but the new dataframe `new_df` data is in a new sheet, `Sheet1`.

The objective is to keep the existing `tables` sheet, while overwriting the data sheet with the data from the new dataframe `new_df`.